# Serialization Library for C++

Tags: c++, serialization

I am writing a client side library and I have to send C++ objects and primitive data types through socket. I have come across Boost and ProtoBuf libraries for serialization but we have to define message format to send data. I am trying to find some library in which I don't have to write message formats and able to send primitive data types and objects.
Is there any library for c/c++ out there?
Thanks

Comment: As C++ doesn't have rich introspection facilities like, say, Java, I don't think such a thing is possible. Both boost::serialization and protobufs are good options, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Remote Call Framework](http://www.deltavsoft.com/index.html) OR [Protobuf-Remote](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-remote/wiki/GettingStartedCpp) Both of them support primitive (and more) types without modifications. You can support more types by doing some configurations.